# ¿Qué sentencia debo ocupar para la siguiente frase?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy desarrollando un ejercicio en Oracle SQLDEVELOPER y me encontré con este requerimiento.

**Las propiedades de tipo local no poseen dormitorios por lo tanto cuando se inserte una propiedad de ese tipo la columna nro_dormitorios de la tabla propiedad debe quedar con valor por defecto CERO.**

He estado un buen rato intentando con `CHECK(), SET DEFAULT 0` pero no me esta funcionando, ¿Alguna idea?

PD1: ¿Puedo realizar esto sin tener que usar PL/SQL?

PD2: Ambos campos se encuentran en la misma tabla (PROPIEDAD)

Answer (score 0):

de lo que puedo observar, el ejercicio pide que de forma predeterminada
se asigne el valor 0 al insertar un nuevo registro en la tabla. Debido a que no se presenta mayor información, muestro un escenario del planteamiento.

El valor del Nro_Camas depende del campo Tipo, entonces se puede utilizar un trigger
de base de datos, para que asigne el valor Cero al insertar registros, para
propiedades de tipo 'LOCAL'. Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE PROPIEDAD 
(PROPIEDAD_ID NUMBER(5),
 TIPO         VARCHAR2(15),
 NRO_CAMAS    NUMBER(5)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG01_PROPIEDAD 
BEFORE INSERT 
  ON PROPIEDAD 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   -- Se valida si el campo Tipo es LOCAL 
   IF UPPER(:NEW.TIPO) = 'LOCAL' THEN
       :NEW.NRO_CAMAS := 0;
   END IF;
END;

-- Luego de este insert al consultar los datos sí debe mantener 12 en Nro_Camas
INSERT INTO PROPIEDAD(CODIGO, TIPO, NRO_CAMAS)
VALUES (1, 'EXTERNA', 12);

-- Luego de este insert al consultar los datos debe mostrar 0 en Nro_Camas
INSERT INTO PROPIEDAD(CODIGO, TIPO, NRO_CAMAS)
VALUES (2, 'LOCAL', 20);
```

Espero que sea de ayuda.